# ラインが変わるごとに任意のコマンドを呼び出したい

Tags: bash

`bash`上で、エンターを押して、ラインが変わるさいに、何らかのコマンドを実行したいのですが、そのようなフックの方法があるのでしょうか。具体的には下のような感じです:

```
$ cat foobar.txt
# run anything command
$ #Enter
# run anything command
$
```

この `# run anything command` という部分で、何らかのコマンドが実行されるような感じをイメージしています。

## 追記

任意のコマンドの実行タイミングを記述するのを忘れていました。`cat foobar.txt`というコマンドを入力したあとであるならば、`foobar.txt`の内容が表示されたあとに、任意のコマンドが実行されるような流れが望ましいです。

Comment: こちら [Does bash have a hook that is run before executing a command?](http://superuser.com/questions/175799/does-bash-have-a-hook-that-is-run-before-executing-a-command) が参考になるのではないでしょうか。

Answer (score 3):

trapコマンドで疑似シグナルDEBUGに処理を割り当てると、入力したコマンドの実行前に処理が実行されます。空エンターでは実行されませんが。

```
$ trap 'echo Yo' DEBUG
$ echo Hello
Yo
Hello
```

Answer (score 3):

[`PS1` シェル変数](http://linuxjm.sourceforge.jp/html/GNU_bash/man1/bash.1.html) ！！ フックではないけれど。

タイミングは、「プロンプトが毎回表示される直前」ですね。

```
PS1="$(echo '(ﾉ￣ω￣)ﾉ\n')$PS1"
```

*※ 環境によって無駄な改行が入るので `\n` を取り除くようにしてください。*

---

#### 追記:

前回実行したコマンドを盛り込みたければ

```
PS1="$(echo '(ﾉ￣ω￣)ﾉ ohh... $(fc -ln -2 | tail -n 1)\n')$PS1"
```

*※ 実用では、自前の function に委譲して、チェックやトリムをすることになると思います*

Comment: PS1 は環境変数ではありません。シェル変数です。

Comment: 指摘助かります。修正しました。(SOでは、直接編集して頂くこともできますよ。）

Answer (score 3):

`PROMPT_COMMAND` が使えないでしょうか？ プロンプト(`PS1`)が表示されるたびに実行されます。

```
$ function hoge(){ date; }
$ PROMPT_COMMAND=hoge
2015年  1月 15日 木曜日 20:39:32 JST
$ cat foobar.txt
this is foobar.txt
2015年  1月 15日 木曜日 20:39:35 JST
$ 
2015年  1月 15日 木曜日 20:39:40 JST
$
```

Comment: `export` は不要ですね。

Comment: ご指摘の通り export は不要でした。

Answer (score 1):

フックではなく、さらにいろいろ問題がありそうなスクリプトですが、以下を実行するとご要望を叶えることができそうです。
ただし、bashの機能がほぼほぼ失われるので実用的ではないかと思いますが……。

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -p "[auto] $ " command ; do
    $command
    echo auto # write command to run automatically
done
```

Answer (score 1):

`while read` の別解として...
実行するコマンドが1行で書ける様な物ならば、xargs が使えると思います。

```
cat foo.log | xargs -i sh -c "echo '{}' && my-command"
```

`{}` の部分が行に置き換わります。